# Linux Backup Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, backup

I am trying to create a bash script that backup the whole /dev/sda1 to /mnt/Backup

```
/dev/sda1       457G  3.5G  431G   1% /
/dev/sdb1       2.8T  3.0G  2.8T   1% /mnt/Backup
```

The script that have is :

```
START=$(date +%D)
FOLDER_NAME=`echo $START | tr -s '/' | tr '/' '_'`
SOURCE_PATH='/media /bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /lib /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /selinux /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var'
SOURCE_PATH='/'
FOLDER_PATH='/mnt/Backup'
BACKUP_PATH=$FOLDER_PATH/Bkp_$FOLDER_NAME
mkdir -p '$BACKUP_PATH'
cp -r $SOURCE_PATH $BACKUP_PATH
```

As you can see above on the source path i have tried naming all the folders i wanted to back up but when i run with that path i get an error : this is not a directory

Then i tried the source path "/" below and the copy start but get stucked on

```
cp: reading `/proc/sysrq-trigger': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/mnt/Backup/Bkp_09_14_13/proc/sysrq-trigger': Input/output error
```

The question is how can i change my script to successfully backup the sda1 to sdb1

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `/proc` is a virtual filesystem, why are you trying to back it up?

Comment: HI Barmar I am trying to back up everything that is in sda1 and the /proc happen to be there

Comment: `mkdir -p "$BACKUP_PATH"` (with _double quotes_) might help a little bit...

Comment: Hi gniourf The mkdir command is already working on another script that i already have. the problem here appears to be only how to copy all the data from sda1 to sdb1

Comment: `/proc` isn't on `sda1`. Do `df /proc`.

Comment: Hey Barmar the source_path='/' contain /proc

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/sda1` is mounted as your root filesystem, doing a recursive copy on it would also include the mounted filesystems under its directories. You can mount it again on another directory e.g. `/mnt/system` then do a recursive copy from it. I suggest using `cp -a` and not just `-r` as well.

Comment: Hi konsolebox thanks for your reply. do you think if i only change from "cp -r" to "cp -a" the script will finish copying without errors?

Comment: I feel like it would work but I haven't tried that yet actually. Most of the time I just mount my system on another directory before backing it up. Do you intend to copy other files from other filesystems as well? e.g. tmpfs in /tmp, udev in /dev, sysfs on /sys? I don't think they would be necessary for the backup.

Comment: You could just do `mkdir -p /mnt/system; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/system; cd /mnt/system; cp -a * /somewhere`

Comment: THe only backup required is the '/' on sda1

Comment: i have a test linux machine at work and i will try your option on monday morning before aplly it onto a live environment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your actual program, but here are some little things:

```
START=$(date +%D)
FOLDER_NAME=`echo $START | tr -s '/' | tr '/' '_'`
```

Both `$()` and `` ` ` `` do exactly the same. Why would you use both in one script? Prefer `$()` over backticks because they can be nested. Also, what is the point of `tr -s '/'` ? First of all, it can be condensed to one tr:

```
echo "$START" | tr -s '/' '_'
```

But considering that `date +%D` will never return repeated slashes you can use pure bash parameter expansion:

```
FOLDER_NAME=${START//\//_}
```

How could this even work: `mkdir -p '$BACKUP_PATH'` ? Variables in single quotes are not expanded. Change to `mkdir -p "$BACKUP_PATH"`

`$SOURCE_PATH` does not need quotes in `cp -r $SOURCE_PATH $BACKUP_PATH`, because you want it to be split into different parameters. That is right. But you have to `$BACKUP_PATH` because you want it to be a single parameter.

So, here is your script with small improvements:

```
START=$(date +%D)
FOLDER_NAME=${START//\//_}
SOURCE_PATH='/media /bin /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /lib /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /selinux /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var'
SOURCE_PATH='/'
FOLDER_PATH='/mnt/Backup'
BACKUP_PATH=$FOLDER_PATH/Bkp_$FOLDER_NAME
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_PATH"
cp -r $SOURCE_PATH "$BACKUP_PATH"
```

Comment: HI Aleks I will try running this improved script on monday morning in a test environment and will let you know how does it run. thanks you very much for you time. apreciated